# Data Reader em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Olá a comunidade python.

Sou estudante de economia e iniciante em python.

Estou desenvolvendo um código para buscar o retorno na compra de ações, buy and hold. Porém tenho um problema, no que tange a busca na API do yahoo finance, a ideia do código é poder adicionar através de input várias ações compradas em datas diferentes, porém o que acontece é que quando extrai as informaçoes o dataframe vem com uma só data inicial(a data mais recente), e não com as datas adicionadas em cada input.
Exemplificando: Quando entro com os valores das ações e da data de compra, por exemplo ITUB4.SA 12-03-2019 e ITSA4.SA 23-12-2019, ao executar o for in para baixar os dados de fechamento das ações, ele considera a data 23-12-2019 para as duas ações e não datas separadas para cada ação. Meu problema creio que seja no for.
Peço desculpas pelo modo rudimentar de escrever o código, estou iniciando.
Aceito dicas que possa melhorar o código.

Segue o código:

````
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

#Criar input de quantas loop for precisa rodar
n = int(input('Quantas ações você tem em sua carteira?'))

#cria o dicionario das acoes 
acoes_dictionary = {}

#Roda o loop for dos input das acoes e salva no dicionario
for x in range(n):    
    new_key = input('Digite o código da sua ação')
    new_date = input('Digite a data de compra da sua ação ')
    acoes_dictionary[new_key] = new_date

#cria uma lista a partir das keys(código) das ações
cod_acoes = list(acoes_dictionary.keys())

#Cria uma lista a partir dos values(data de compra) das ações
date_acoes = list(acoes_dictionary.values())

#Cria um data framde para salvar a busca da internet das acoes
df = pd.DataFrame()

#Busca o fechamento as ações no yahoo finance
for i,j in zip(cod_acoes,date_acoes):
    df[i,j] = wb.DataReader(i, data_source='yahoo', start =j)['Adj Close']

print(df)```
````

Comment: Olá João, faltou explicar o problema melhor. O problema está no yahoo-finance? O que você gostaria de fazer? Juntar o dado que retorna do yahoo-finance com os que você insere manualmente? Peço que explique melhor o problema que precisa ser resolvido

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, creio que o problema esteja no : for i,j in zip(cod_acoes,date_acoes):
    df[i,j] = wb.DataReader(i, data_source='yahoo', start=j). Possivelmente neste j, pois o que acontece, se eu digito por exemplo ITUB4.SA 12-03-2019 e ITSA4.SA 23.12.2019. Quando o for in busca no data reader, ele considera somente a data 23.12.2019 para as duas acoes e nao a data de cada uma.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema, vou deixar o código aberto aqui caso alguém queira usar, vou colocar inteiro mesmo:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

#Criar input de quantas loop for precisa rodar
n = int(input('Quantas ações você tem em sua carteira?'))

#cria o dicionario das acoes 
acoes_dictionary = {}

#Cria a lista de pesos
pesos=[]

#Roda o loop for dos input das acoes e salva no dicionario
for x in range(n):
    new_value = input('Digite o código da sua ação')
    new_key = input('Digite a data de compra da sua ação ')
    acoes_dictionary[new_key] = new_value
    pesos.append(input('Qual o peso da ação em sua carteira?'))

#Cria uma lista a partir dos values(data de compra) das ações
date_acoes = list(acoes_dictionary.keys())

#cria uma lista a partir das keys(código) das ações
cod_acoes = list(acoes_dictionary.values())

#Cria uma lista a partir dos dados das listas acima
list_acoes = list(zip(cod_acoes,date_acoes))

#Cria um Data Frame novo
data= pd.DataFrame()

#Cria uma função que busca as informações i e j no yahoo finance
def get_data(i,j):
    return data.append((wb.DataReader(i, data_source='yahoo',start=j)['Adj Close']))

#Cria um data framde para salvar a busca da internet das acoes
df = pd.DataFrame()

#Busca o fechamento as ações no yahoo finance
for i,j in zip(cod_acoes,date_acoes):
    df =  df.append(get_data(i,j))

#Faz a transposta da matriz    
df = df.T

#Renomeia as colunas
df.columns = [cod_acoes] 

#Cria a lista que vai ficar os valores do retorno
lista_retorno = []

#Cria uma lista de pesos nova
pesos_2 = []

#Cria um loop for para percorrer os items na lista de pesos e salvar como um item
for x in pesos:
    item = x

    #Cria um loop for para percorrer os itens y que estão na lista ['%']
    for y in ['%']:
        #substitui na variavel item os valores dentro da lista ['%'] por ''
        item = item.replace(y, "")
    #Salva esse resultado na lista pesos_2    
    pesos_2.append(item)

#Cria a lista pesos_3
pesos_3=[]

#Cria um loop for para percorrer cada item dentro da lista pesos_2, transforma em float e divide por 100
for x in pesos_2:
    x = float(x)
    x = x/100
    #Salva o resultado na lista peso_3
    pesos_3.append(x)

#Divide o valor de t pelo valor de t-1 e subtrai 1, acha o retorno diario
returns=(df/df.shift(1))-1

#Soma os retornos diários
total_returns = returns.sum()

#Transforma a lista pesos_3 em um vetor
pesos_3 = np.array(pesos_3)

#multiplica os retornos pelo peso
np.dot(total_returns,pesos_3)

#Salva a matriz df de modo que o primeiro item seja o numero, pois como a quantidade de dias não são iguais precisa
#ler o gráfico do mais recente indo para o mais velho
df_grafico = df.iloc[::-1]

#Plota o gráfico
(df_grafico/df_grafico.iloc[0]).plot(figsize=(15,6))
plt.show()

#printa o retorno do portifolio
pfolio_1='O retorno da sua carteira é de '+ str(round(np.dot(total_returns,pesos_3),5)*100)+'%'
print(pfolio_1)
```